# Do we really need Zorn's lemma to prove the existence of prime ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $A$ be a ring, $S$ a multiplicative set, and $I$ an ideal  of $A$ disjoint from $S$; then there exists a prime ideal $P$ of $A$ containing $I$ and disjoint from $S$.

The author of the book I'm reading, proves this by saying:

> Suppose that I can find an ideal $P\supset I$ maximal subject to the condition $P\cap S=\emptyset$. I claim that $P$ is a prime ideal.

He then shows that $P$ is indeed a prime ideal and then uses Zorn's lemma to show we can find such a $P$. (You might call this the standard proof.)

But why can't we just define $P:=A\backslash S$. It is prime, contains $I$ and is disjoint from $S$. Where am I off, when I think this will do?

I think that there's probably something I've overlooked, or else the author would have just used this argument.

Comment: $A \backslash S$ is not necessarily closed under addition.

Comment: Why would $A \setminus S$ be an ideal?

Comment: If S is $\{1\}$ and the ring has some other invertible element?

Comment: @Nate Of course. I should have thought of that. I've been sweating over this for 30 minutes now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove this from the unanswered questions; the problem is that $A\backslash S$ is not necessarily closed under addition and thus there's no reason to expect that it's an ideal. A counterexample would be $S=\{1\}$, where $A$ has other invertible elements.

With thanks to *Nate, mt_* and *brick*.